# Unexpected behavior from launching a method call on a loop variable as a goroutine

Tags: loops, go, pointers, goroutine, data-race

I read this [article](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables) and decided to repeat such behavior myself and experiment with that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type User struct {
    i    int
    token string
}

func NewUser(i int, token string) User {
    user := User{token: fmt.Sprint(i), i: i}
    return user
}

func (u *User) PrintAddr() {
    fmt.Printf("%d (PrintAddr): %p\n", u.i, u)
}

func main() {
    users := make([]User, 4)
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        user := NewUser(i, "")
        users[i] = user
    }
    
    for i, user := range users {
        go user.PrintAddr()
        go users[i].PrintAddr()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l8Gz1cRMYAw))

Here is the code output:

```
1 (PrintAddr): 0xc000056198
2 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000561b0
0 (PrintAddr): 0xc000056180
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc00000c030
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc00000c030
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc00000c030
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc00000c030
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000561c8
```

I also don't understand, why are 4 of 5 `3 (PrintAddr)` are `0xc00000c030`, and the last one is different?

---

However, if I use a *pointer* array instead of *value* array, like this,

```
func NewUser(i int, token string) *User {
    user := &User{token: fmt.Sprint(i), i: i}
    return user
}
// -snip-
func main() {
    users := make([]*User, 4)
    // -snip-
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rsQn2fuP5JR))

then everything's fine here and each entry is printed exactly 2 times with the same address:

```
1 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae030
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae060
2 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae048
2 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae048
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae060
1 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae030
0 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae018
0 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000ae018
```

But why did the situation in the article not apply here and I didn't get many `3 (PrintAddr)` instead?

Comment: *"I also don't understand, why are 4 of 5 `3 (PrintAddr)` are `0xc00000c030`, and the last one is different?"* -- The 4 instances of `3 (PrintAddr): 0xc00000c030` are the result of `user.PrintAddr()`. The `3 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000561c8` instance, and the `1,2,0 (PrintAddr) 0x...` instances, are the result of `users[i].PrintAddr()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

Your first version has a *synchronisation bug*, which manifests itself as a *data race*:

```
$ go run -race main.go
0 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000b4018
0 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000c2120
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c0000b4018 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      redacted/main.go:29 +0x1e5

Previous read at 0x00c0000b4018 by goroutine 7:
  main.(*User).PrintAddr()
      redacted/main.go:19 +0x44

Goroutine 7 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      redacted/main.go:30 +0x244
==================
1 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000b4018
1 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000c2138
2 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000b4018
2 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000c2150
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000b4018
3 (PrintAddr): 0xc0000c2168
Found 1 data race(s)
```

The `for` loop (line 29) keeps updating loop variable `user` *while* (i.e. in a concurrent manner without proper synchronisation) the `PrintAddr` method accesses it via its pointer receiver (line 19). Note that if you don't start `user.PrintAddr()` as a goroutine on line 30, the problem goes away.

The problem and a solution to it are actually given at the bottom of [the Wiki you link to](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables).

> But why did the situation in the article not apply here and I didn't get many `3 (PrintAddr)` instead?

That synchronisation bug is a source of undesired undeterminism. In particular, you cannot predict how many times (if any) `3 (PrintAddr)` will be printed, and that number may vary from one execution to the next. In fact, scroll up and see for yourself: in my execution with the race detector on, the output happened to feature two of each integer between 0 and 3, despite the bug; but there's no guarantee for that.

### Solution

Simply shadow loop variable `user` at the top of the loop and the problem goes away:

```
for i, user := range users {
    user := user // <---
    go user.PrintAddr()
    go users[i].PrintAddr()
}
```

`PrintAddr` will now operate on the innermost `user` variable, which is not updated by the `for` loop on line 29.

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/o3CQ2zlHFfZ))

#### Addendum

You should also use a wait group to wait for all your goroutines to finish. `time.Sleep` is no way to coordinate goroutines.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't looking for a solution, but for an explanation, why exactly that happened so

Answer (score 2):

The first version of your code that ranges over the value *slice* is [taking the address of the iterator variable.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable). Why?

The method `PrintAddr` is defined on the pointer receiver:

```
func (u *User) PrintAddr() {
    fmt.Printf("%d (PrintAddr): %p\n", u.i, u)
}
```

In the for loop the `user` iteration variable is reused at every loop and assigned the next value in the slice. Therefore it is the same variable. But you are *taking its address by calling a method that was defined on the pointer receiver*:

```
    users := make([]User, 4)
    // ...
    for i, user := range users {
        go user.PrintAddr()
        go users[i].PrintAddr()
    }
```

[Calling](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) the method on the value equals to `(&user).PrintAddr()`:

> If `x` is addressable and &x's method set contains `m`, `x.m()` is shorthand for `(&x).m()`

Indexing the slice instead works as expected because you are accessing the actual `i`-th value in the slice, instead of using the iterator var.

Changing the slice to hold pointer values also works around this issue because the iterator var is now a copy of the pointer to the `User` value.

Comment: `The first version of your code that ranges over the value slice is taking the address of the iterator variable..`
Yes, I repeated the mistake from the article and tried to experiment with it

Comment: I did that on purpose to understand what's going on better

Comment: `Indexing the slice instead works as expected because you are accessing the actual i-th value in the slice, instead of using the iterator var.`
But 1. it doesn't work as expected (`go users[i].PrintAddr()` printed the same address at least twice)
2. `i` is the same variable that is reused at every loop, similar to `user`, right? so it has the same "problem", hasn't it?

Comment: `Changing the slice to hold pointer values also works around this issue because the iterator var is now a copy of the pointer to the User value.`
Yes, sure, but in my understanding of this, it is still a variable that just changes with each iteration so there should be the same "problem", but, for some reason, no...

Comment: @Wynell `i` has not the same problem bc you are not addressing it. when the slice holds `*User` values, the iterator var is indeed reused as well, but when you call the method on it there's no implicit addressing. The point being: don't address the iterator variable.